# How can I make my formatting conditional with pipes in angular html

Tags: angular, formatting, angular-pipe

How can I do some conditional formatting. The code below formats it to two decimal places. However sometimes the row[column.props] comes out as not of type number. Sometimes it has a value of text like 'n/a' how can I do conditional formatting in this case? I don't want to format it as number if it is not a number.

```
<td *ngFor = "let column of headers">
  {{row[column.prop] | number: '1.1-2'}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` in your template to see if the value is a number.  If the value is not a number use `else` to render a different template.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public values: any[] = [1.23, 11.134223, 'n/a', 0, 'n/a'];
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let val of values">
  <div *ngIf="+val; else nonNumberTemplate">{{ val | number: '1.1-2' }}</div>
  <ng-template #nonNumberTemplate>
    <div>{{ val }}</div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5gmgnu